# Integer part of $\sum^{9999}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the integer part of $$\sum^{9999}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k}}.$$

Is there any way without using definite integration or telescopic series?

What I tried: integration means summation and we have $$\sum^{9999}_{k=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{k}}\approx \int^{10,000}_{1}\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{4}}}dx=\frac{4}{3}\cdot 1000$$
How do I solve it? Help me for that problem. Thanks.

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1965476p13608385

Answer (score 5):

Yes, integration is the right tool to find sufficiently precise bounds for the given summation.
For $x>1$, we have that
$$\frac1{\sqrt[4]{x}}\le\frac1{\sqrt[4]{\lfloor x\rfloor}}<\frac1{\sqrt[4]{x-1}}$$
and therefore 
$$1332=\int_1^{10000}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]{x}}<\sum_{n=1}^{9999}\frac1{\sqrt[4]{n}}<1+\int_2^{10000}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]{x-1}}=1+\int_1^{9999}\frac{dx}{\sqrt[4]{x}}<1+1332.$$
Hence the integer part is $1332$.